# Web app to find the location from an image

Tags: images, crowdsourcing, geo-location

I'm looking for a web app that I came across almost a year ago and haven't been able to find since. The web app uses crowdsourcing to identify locations from photos uploaded by users.

Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Comment: Asking for a website is off-topic here. Please rephrase your question by asking "I want a webapp that does XYZ", otherwise it will be closed. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think he's asking for a web app so much as a platform based on the original question (the former is a program like Google Docs the later a p2p website like eBay) so I will propose an edit to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I resolved myself to sit down and find this site again, and I'm glad to report that after at least 30 minutes of all sorts of online detective work, creative Googling and trying to recreate the search terms I used to find the site initially, I finally found it:

## [Where Is This?](http://www.where-is-this.com)

- **4,406 places submitted**
- **3,481 placed successfully located**
- **Browse locations by country**
- **Search locations by country, or by filters such as "Best rated" and "Hotly debated"**

I'm not sure whether anyone else will get as much use out of this site as I will, but I've personally found it really useful in the past and hope to do so in the future, so needless to say I'm glad to have found it again.

It's a lot more fully-fledged and feature-heavy a service than the alternatives, including the popular sub-Reddit. Granted, that may be slightly offset by the relatively small community at the moment, but with such a feature-powerful platform and smooth UI, I feel like it's only a matter of time before it starts to gain some much-deserved traction and become the defacto site for the purpose.

Comment: Reading this answer back, I realise it sounds like an ad, and that I'm affiliated with the site in some way, but I honestly just have a passion for web apps and sites that do one or a few things well, and this one does exactly that. It really deserves more recognition than it has, I couldn't find anything linking to it on any other site. Plus, I spent half an hour finding it!

Answer (score 2):

A crowdsourced platform that may meet these criteria is [Scoutt](https://www.scoutt.com/) (also see http://petapixel.com/2015/07/17/scoutt-a-crowdsourced-map-for-finding-and-sharing-photo-locations/ ).

Another possibility is https://www.reddit.com/r/wherewasthistaken/ .

Comment: Definitely not Scoutt, it was a cleaner interface and wasn't targeted to photographers. The premise was to identify places that the general public had come across in some image somewhere, rather than to find places that would be good to photographs.

As for the sub-reddit, obviously it isn't that, but I wasn't aware of it, and it could be an awesome alternative if I can't find the site I'm looking for. I'll have to wait till Reddit is back up to check it out though, it's been down for a few hours where I am.

Comment: @Hashim If there's a landmark in the background they can identify it with computer image recognition. I know I've seen that service, I'm thinking maybe Google but I'm not sure offhand.

Comment: @Hack-R: The question was off-topic, I rephrased it, please update your answer if needed, thanks! Also, please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality Cheers!

Comment: @Hashim: Our goal is to find webapps that fit a set of features described in your question. Even if that is not *the* webapp you were thinking about. That way, you might even discover a better one! :-)

Comment: I'm looking for this particular web app because I know from the extensive research I've done that there is no better one, no other alternative crowd-sources them except Reddit, and Reddit's been down for a long while for me.

Comment: @Hashim Just for the record Reddit worked for me last night and right now; their server status doesn't show they were ever down. You may have a blacklisted IP; try a proxy.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Image Identification Project](https://www.imageidentify.com/) from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

You drop an image onto the webapp and it has a go at identifying it.  It works pretty well for landmarks.

[image: Screenshot - Eiffel Tower]

The identification is not perfect and you may just get a generic answer like "*Building*", which isn't as helpful as you would like.  However, it may go some way towards what you are after.

Comment: @nicolasRaoul Do you reckon that is Paris? Or Tokyo? ;-)